# Why does one Java process on Linux is working at the same speed as when starte twice?

Tags: java, linux, performance

I have a Java Soap Client that send some xml files to a remote server to be processed.

It uses java 1.7's `java.nio.file.WatchEvent<Path>` (almost just like it's explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java)) to monitor new files added to a directory.

It is processing about 2 or 3 files per minute.

Looking for a way to increase the speed of files sent and processed I decided to start the same jar twice, monitoring different directories of course.

I can't explain why both processes are still processing about 2 or 3 files per minute. I doubt the problem is in the remote server, since I have a log showing the moment when each file begins and ends it's processing, and it shows almost the same behavior when using only one linux process than when using two.

**Any ideas about why is this happening?**

P.S.1 Don't know exactly what information should I add here. Feel free to ask.

P.S.2 The server is a virtual one and is using:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Thnx.

## Update 1

I mean the total throughput is the same when using only one linux process than when using two.

## Update 2

```
 vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 5  0      0 1716872      0      0    0    0  1874  1960    0    6 17  7 74  2  0
```

## Update 3

Ok, there should be a bottleneck somewhere other than cpu.

**Any suggestions on what tool or tools should I use to find it?** (Remember, it's a Java application)

Comment: When you say "working at the same speed", do you mean that the two processes _combined_ work at the same speed as the single process, or both _individually_? I'd assume the first case. Probably, the bottleneck is file access or bandwidth, and that won't double by running the process on two cores.

Comment: Amdahl's law says you're just not CPU-bound.

Comment: I don't understand. How quickly do the files appear? Are you starving one of the processes? Are *both* processes handling 2-3 FPM, or is the *total* throughput 2-3 FPM? Where are the processes spending their time? If it's IO then it's an IO issue and not related to the number of processes.

Comment: Do you know how to monitorize the bandwith or the disk access? I think this things are limiting you.

Comment: Also, I don't quite see how the logs rule out the remote server as the bottleneck...

Comment: Most likely you have a bottleneck such as the disk IO, network IO or memory bus. Adding more CPU won't make a difference if this is the case so you don't see a speed difference. Adding more CPU only helps if you have CPU bottleneck.

Comment: @tobias_k The logs rule out the remote server, I think, since I see 2 or 3 messages of "start processing" per minute, and also 2 or 3 messages of "end processing" per minute when using only one linux process. It is just the same when using two linux processes. Am I right?

Comment: @tobias_k. If I saw atleast 6 messages per minute about starting processing, and only 3 about ending processing... then I would know the problem is in the remote server. I think.

Comment: @elysch I see your point, but that may also depend on how the server is implemented. For instance, it might be programmed in a way that it will only ever process three tasks in parallel. How long do those tasks take, and in what intervals are they started? If they are all started immediately and then need a few dozens of seconds to complete, it's more likely the server's fault, then if they are started (i.e. are received) only one every few seconds. Also, how big are those XML files?

Comment: @tobias_k They are a few KB each. the vast majority are smaller than 8KB. I'll contact the server administrator to ask about limits it may have. But for example: a few minutes ago, I had 27 files in one directory and 20 in the other one and the combined log still was showing only 2 or 3 "starting process" messages every minute (in total for BOTH Linux processes)

Comment: What I missed to comment is that the files are added gradually. So... It may be processing a few files, before it can read the next set of files added.

Comment: The processing takes from 10 to 45 seconds per file. Since now I have two separated processes, should now be processed more than 4 or 5 files per minute, but it isn't happening

Answer (score 1):

Divide-and-conquer is the best approach to solving this question.

For example, create one process that only finds the files and prints that it has found each, then measure the rate at which that runs.  If it's slow, then the inbound file scanning is the slow point - whether that's due to the speed at which files are added, filesystem slowness, or other needing to then be diagnosed.

Create a second process that continually performs the file processing using some fixed content.  Record when the processing stops and starts.

Once you have the smallest code that reproduces the problem, you'll have a much better idea where to find the source of the slowness.

Comment: I like this idea... I'll try it. Thanks. (I'm not accepting it as the answer yet, to give a chance to get other ideas)